# Simple homepage HTML query

Tags: html, redirect

I recently updated my homepage to link to another site. I updated the index.html file with the following code (web addresses anonymised here for privacy) ...

[Homepage HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3z8a.png)

My homepage redirects to "example.com" with a slight lag. While example.com is waiting to load, my homepage displays the following characters ...

[Homepage characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrTQI.png)

I have no idea why this is happening. Can anyone offer advice as to what code I need to prevent these characters from showing?

Ideally I would like my homepage to redirect to example.com with no lag, after 0 seconds, and with no "Your browser is being redirected to example.com in 10 seconds; click here to be redirected immediately" message.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved with php. Simply rename your index.html file to index.php (I assume your webserver can handle php).

Then delete all of your code in index.php and put the following in:

```php
<?PHP

  header("location: https://example.com/");

?>
```

This code immediately redirects the page to example.com, neat!

Comment: @Komodein Nice, don’t forget to mark the question as answered!

Answer (score 0):

despite that it is better to do a server-side-redirect as Chiel advises you, I looked into your problem itself (see below).
Think about it that you can also create a redirect for Apache using a [httaccess](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/all/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-.htaccess-file) file, or in the Nginx [config](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216456087-Creating-redirects-with-Nginx) (depending which you are using, but assuming apache here)

Now to the strange characters: 
The problem of the characters might be unrelated to the reload itself. it might be an encoding problem.

With which encoding dit you saved the HTML-file? `utf-8` should be correct, as many also should also be correct. but in case of doubt, save it as `utf-8` and try again.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. I used Chiel's PHP script.